# An error when compiling C and S files together

Tags: c, assembly, makefile

I have this error :

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/build/glibc-mqlSLF/glibc-2.19/csu/../ports/sysdeps/arm/start.S:119: undefined reference to `main'
```

When I try to execute my makefile :

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.
DEBUGFLAGS=-D NDEBUG -O3
RM=rm -f
default: all

all: fib.o bigint.o bigintadd.o
    $(CC) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -o fib fib.o bigint.o bigintadd.o

fib.o: fib.c bigint.h
    $(CC) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -c fib.c -o fib.o $(CFLAGS)

bigint.o: bigint.c bigint.h bigintprivate.h
    $(CC) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -c bigint.c -o bigint.o $(CFLAGS)

bigintadd.o: bigintadd.s bigint.h bigintprivate.h
    as -o bigintadd.o bigintadd.s $(CFLAGS)
    $(CC) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -s bigintadd.s -o bigintadd.o $(CFLAGS)



clean:
    $(RM) fib fib.o bigint.o bigintadd.o
```

"The main" branch in my .s file is named BigInt_add as .c files call this function. I tried to make it _start or main, but then the compiler complains about not finding a BigInt_add branch.

Any suggestions why this happens ?

Comment: Do you have `main` in C part? (as I believe the error happens during linking, not during compilation, and it is not assembly related, but the `main` "entry point" is missing in your sources .. you can define it in assembly file too, but I would expect it in `fib.c`)

Comment: yes, I do have main in fib.c @Ped7g

Comment: Why are you both assembling AND compiling bigintadd.s...?

Comment: @TonyB because I am quite new to assembly and gcc, it might be a mistake

Comment: Did you make it `.globl`? Post a [MCVE]!

Comment: Remove the "compile" of bigintadd.s (leaving the "assemble" of it) and see if that fixes your problem...

Comment: I removed the following line :

$(CC) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -s bigintadd.s -o bigintadd.o $(CFLAGS)

And it helped ! Thank you @TonyB !

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I tried to compile the .s file by having the following line :

```
$(CC) $(DEBUGFLAGS) -s bigintadd.s -o bigintadd.o $(CFLAGS)
```

When I removed it , the problem was solved.